# Can someone tell me how the function is targeting the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im not well adversed with Jquery and I need to know how the function in this script knows what element to modify.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/44/)**

I know it has somthing to do with;

```
$(function(){
var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '.trigger', // link button id
    objSlidePanel: '', // slide div class or id
}

settings.objSlidePanel = "#"+ $(this).data('content') +"";
```

I just dont know how it targets the element with the class panel though, if you understand what im trying to say... :/

Comment: settings.objSlidePanel = "#"+ $(this).data('content') +""; this corresponds to generation of selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line selects the element:

```
settings.objSlidePanel = "#"+ $(this).data('content') +"";
```

What it does is it takes the element that is currently clicked `$(this)` and checks the data attribute 'content'... Because you've defined `data-content="panel-one"` for example... It will trigger the item with that id since your `settings.objSlidePanel` will be equal to `"#panel-one"`

Comment: So if I wanted to target two elements, say for example the panel and the page wrapper. I would add the page wrapper class to the data-content, like so. data-content="panel-one, wrapper". or would I need to add multiple data contents to an element?

Comment: So you understand what im trying to achieve, I need to expand the wrapper div in height every time I open a specific panel. I get the jist of the code just unsure on how it communicates with the HTML

Comment: you would need to add ", #wrapper" ... since the id selector needs to be present as well for the second element. Or you could change the code and make it split on the "," and then add the "#" in a javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/53/) - Try clicking on `Panel One` in the fiddle.

This what is selecting element :-

```
settings.objSlidePanel = "#" + $(this).data('content') + "";
alert(settings.objSlidePanel);
```

Explanation :-

```
"#" + $(this).data('content') + ""
```

ID of Element is selected in this way

1. #
2. Value of `$(this).data('content')` = `panel-one`  Getting the data-content property value of `<a>`

`// <a class="trigger" data-content="panel-one">Panel One</a>`

So collectively string becomes `"#panel-one"`

Answer (score 1):

```
var settings = {
  objSlideTrigger: '.trigger',// link button id
  objSlidePanel: '',// slide div class or id
}

// basically your script tells you that everything that has a class of .trigger
// is binded by a click and $(this) is used to access the html or dom that you've binded
// or that has a click event of that selector

$(settings.objSlideTrigger).bind('click', function() {

  // Going back to your question
  // $(this) <--- refers to the one you clicked on <a class="trigger" data-content="panel-#">
  // $(this).data('content') actually gets the data-content attribute of the one you've clicked

  settings.objSlidePanel = "#" + $(this).data('content') + "";

  // the code above gets the value
  // and now you're using it by
  // $(settings.objSlidePanel) or equivalent to
  // $("#" + $(this).data('content'));
  // or $("#panel-one");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

at first: take a look at jQuery UI tabs

for your question:

```
settings.objSlidePanel = $("#"+ $(this).data('content'))
```

but the main issue it is how to hide previous shown panel